# Should you close *out*?

Tags: clojure, stdout, leiningen

Should you close `*out*` (standard output)? For example, via the `with-open` macro:

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(with-open [w (io/writer *out*)]
  (.write w "foo"))
```

If I run this via Leiningen's (v2.7.0) `lein run`, I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(StreamEncoder.java:45)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:140)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at clojure.core$flush.invokeStatic(core.clj:3691)
    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:423)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:386)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
```

Otherwise, the code works fine.

Comment: Why not write directly to `*out*`?

Comment: Uniform interface. It can be either a `java.io.File` or `*out*`.

Comment: There are definitely reasons you might want to (search on daemonizing a process), but I think you lose a lot by doing so.  Primarily, an easy way to get information to the user both from your app directly and from the Java runtime (unhandled exceptions).  Outside of Java, you might dup the file handle and hand it off, but in Java that kind of thing is harder to do.  You'd probably want to write your own routine specifically for wrapping *out* that gives you a Writer but doesn't close the underlying stream when it's done.  I'm not sure if that's a great idea or not though.